# What is the real-time elimination of improbable meanings called in the linguistic literature?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phrase-meaning, psycholinguistics

> He brought some food to eat *on the road*.
>
> He found some beer to drink *in the fridge*.

Is it only reality and sanity that keep us from taking the beer example to mean he would be squashed in the fridge like a contortionist, sipping a beer? Or do the verbs license, or if that is too strong, erect interpretive guide-rails for, adjunct phrases?  Is meaning *accruing* as we parse, eliminating certain possibilities and bringing others to the fore?

What is the real-time elimination of improbable meanings called in the linguistic literature?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147693/discussion-on-question-by-timr-what-is-the-real-time-elimination-of-improbable-m); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as Araucaria's post gets undeleted, there'll be a long answer; in the meantime, the short answer to the OQ is that there is no such name because there is no such procedure. As I mentioned in a comment, mostly we don't notice ambiguities (though comedians take careful notes on them for joke construction), because we're in the local context, not in the word context. If we understand what's going on, the program is working and we don't need to load the debugger.

It's not anything instantaneous; it's continuous. We are looking for contextual clues, and we found them, and we keep them and use them, and anything else is just damn silliness we don't hafta pay attention to. And we don't, mostly. Until we don't understand. And fixing that's far from instantaneous, too.

There are a number of pragmatic constraints that help, like Grice's Maxims, and presuppositions, but in general "real-time elimination of improbable meanings" is something computers do, not humans. Computers have to take whatever comes in at face value; humans don't.

Comment: I think your statement "It's not anything instantaneous; it's continuous. We're looking for contextual clues .. and we keep them ... and anything else is just damn silliness we don't hafta pay attention to" is more or less synonymous with my "Is meaning *accruing* as we parse, eliminating certain possibilities and bringing others to the fore?"

Comment: If "meaning" were a quantity, it could accrue, if we could measure it. Since neither of these are true, the answer to your question is even more problematical. Metaphors are seductive, but they are not reality.

Comment: The phrase "meaning accrues" has been used in the context of sequential vs gestalt mental processes.  It doesn't necessarily involve *quantity*.

Comment: I think your *there is no such procedure* is effectively the same as my *"improbable" meanings don't normally occur to us in the first place, so there's no need to consider and discard them*. Of course, that assumes both speaker and audience speak the same language, AND that the context is one where speaker is saying something that he wants and expects to be understood. That's not always the case with English text being considered *absent full context* by people who don't even know the language very well, and may struggle with both syntax *and* vocabulary (especially, with *written* text).

Comment: I am reminded of an old *Beverly Hillbillies* episode where granny is delighted to find some food to eat on the road.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an established term for "the real-time elimination of improbable meanings". Which usually happens naturally without conscious effort or even *awareness* anyway - "improbable" meanings don't normally occur to us in the first place, so there's no need to consider and discard them.

But the fact that alternative meanings *can* exist at the conscious level for audience / readers is addressed by [Grice's Maxims...](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Eharoldfs/dravling/grice.html)

> 1: **The maxim of quantity**, where one tries to be as informative as one possibly can, and gives as much information as is needed, and no more.

> 2: **The maxim of quality**, where one tries to be truthful, and does not give information that is false or that is not supported by evidence.

> 3: **The maxim of relation**, where one tries to be relevant, and says things that are pertinent to the discussion.

> 4: **The maxim of manner**, when one tries to be as clear, as brief, and as orderly as one can in what one says, and where one avoids obscurity and ambiguity.

Collectively, those 4 elements are often called [the Cooperative Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle) - the primary purpose of language is (accurate, efficient) *communication*, so it would be perverse of a speaker / writer to be deliberately ambiguous / misleading, just as it would be perverse of the audience to assume contextually unlikely (but syntactically *feasible*) interpretations.

So arguably one could say "the real-time elimination of improbable meanings" is simply a manifestation of ***cooperation*** (speaker and audience cooperating to enable successful communication).